# is there a formula for working out the angles of a triangle to make the sides meet at the top?

Tags: triangles

I am doing a GCSE maths foundation paper for revision and one question has a triangle with the base side being 9cm and the other 2 sides 7.5cm. Is there a formula for finding the angles of the triangle given the lengths of each side so that the 2 side lengths  join together at the top to complete the triangle?

Thanks

Comment: cosine rule of triangles.[this will helpful](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://img.docstoccdn.com/thumb/orig/122204151.png&imgrefurl=http://www.docstoc.com/docs/122204151/The-Sine-and-Cosine-Rule&h=1500&w=1125&sz=42&tbnid=tyHIqR4pgmjiyM:&tbnh=107&tbnw=80&prev=/search%3Fq%3Dcosine%2Brule%2Bof%2Btriangle%26tbm%3Disch%26tbo%3Du&zoom=1&q=cosine+rule+of+triangle&usg=__lUFfItjm5CRq6FQxswVn8bmMbq4=&docid=cd2NPBkJrYxJZM&sa=X&ei=yZS0UZDZFcjyrQeEx4GIAg&sqi=2&ved=0CD8Q9QEwBA&dur=500)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

Use cosine [formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines) of triangles

$$\cos A=\frac{7.5^2+7.5^2-9^2}{2\cdot7.5\cdot 7.5}$$

Comment: Hi could you explain what's happening here and how I get the angles to form the triangle?

Comment: @crm, follow the link and you'll get a picture.